# If A is a substructure of B and A is isomorphic to B then A is an elementary substructure of B

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, integers

If $\mathcal A$ is a substructure of $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal A$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal B$, then is it true that $\mathcal A$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathcal B$?

This question arose while I was trying to determine all the elementary substructure of $\mathbb Z$, viewed as a structure for the language $\mathcal L := \{ 0, +, - \}$ as an abelian group.

I have figured that any elementary substructure of $\mathbb Z$ must be of the form $a\mathbb Z$ for some $a \neq 0$. Now I am trying to show the converse. I have determined that $a\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ for any $a \neq 0$. If the answer to my first line of this post is affirmative, then I will get my result.

We know that if $\mathcal A$ is an elementary substructure of $B$, then in particular $\mathcal A$ is equivalent to $\mathcal B$.

If the answer to my first line of this post is no, then is there a way to determine all the elementary substructure of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Another counterexample: consider $([0,1], <)$ and $([-1,1],<).$

Comment: Or $(\mathbb{N},S)$ and $(\mathbb{N}_{>0},S)$, where $\mathbb{N}_{>0} = \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ and $S$ is the successor function.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your main question is **no**, and in fact $\mathbb{Z}$ itself gives us a counterexample: the substructure $\mathbb{E}$ of even integers is clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ itself, but is not an elementary substructure. The failure of elementarity is a good exercise, so I've spoilered it below:

> The element $2$ satisfies the formula $\varphi(x)\equiv\exists y(y+y=x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{E}$.

And this gives us, with a bit of care, a complete characterization of the elementary substructures of $\mathbb{Z}$:

> There aren't any (besides $\mathbb{Z}$ itself of course). Just tweak the above formula to look at $y+...+y$ ($n$ times) instead of $y+y$, for an appropriate choice of $n$.

---

In general, elementary substructurehood is an **extremely strong** condition. Of course it doesn't imply isomorphism-with-the-whole either (consider e.g. the rationals and the reals as linear orders), but most of the time the surprising part of the picture is how strong $\preccurlyeq$ is.

Comment: +1. Maybe worth noting that it's also very interesting to consider situations in which  elementary substructurehood is *not* a strong notion. This leads to the notion of model-completeness and quantifier elimination/reduction theorems.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: This makes me wonder. If $T$ is a theory such that every self-embedding of a model of $T$ is elementary, does $T$ have to be model complete? I did not think about it at all, maybe it's easy.

Comment: @tomasz It's a good question! I'm not sure.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I guess this is at least consistently true. Suppose $T$ is not model complete, as witnessed by $M\leq N$, $M,N\models T$, $M\not\preceq N$, and fix $a\in M$ and $\varphi(x,y)$ such that $M\not\models \exists y\varphi(a,y)$ and $N\models \exists y\varphi(a,y)$. Then let $T'=\operatorname{Th}(N,M,a)$ (with predicate for $M$ and constants for $a$). If $\kappa>\lvert T\rvert$ is strongly inaccessible, then $T'$ will have a saturated model of cardinality $\kappa$ which (as a model of $T$) admits a non-elementary self-embedding.

Comment: I guess the constants for $a$ are not necessary, $\operatorname{Th}(N,M)$ already knows that $M$ is not elementary in $N$. Anyway, the point is that if I'm not mistaken, in a saturated model of $T'$, both the big model and the small one should be saturated models of $T$ of the same cardinality.

Comment: @tomasz Great. To check that if $(N,M)$ is saturated, then $M$ is a saturated model of $T$, one needs to check that for any $L$-type $p(x)$ over a small subset of $M$, the relativization of $p$ to the predicate for the small model is still consistent with the elementary diagram of the pair, which is a small compactness argument.

Comment: Silly remark: If you want to establish consistency, it's better to appeal to GCH for saturated models than inaccessibles, since we can prove GCH is consistent. More serious remark: This is the kind of argument where it's very convenient to use saturated models, but where they're not really necessary. E.g. one can start with a countable model of the theory of the pair and build a chain of models of the theory of the pair, realizing types back and forth, until the big and small models are both homogeneous and realize the same types over $\varnothing$, hence are isomorphic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Right, this is a nice argument. So I guess this is just true in ZFC.